Why does TexStudio run pdflatex so many times?
I am compiling a large document in TexStudio. It takes a lot of time, and in the log, I see this:
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "SAGT2024".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "SAGT2024".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "SAGT2024".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "SAGT2024".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "SAGT2024".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "SAGT2024".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: bibtex.exe "SAGT2024"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2022)
The top-level auxiliary file: SAGT2024.aux
The style file: splncs04.bst
Database file #1: Bibliography/kbp-paper.bib
Warning--empty journal in Doron-Arad_Kulik_Shachnai_2022
Warning--there's a number but no volume in Doron-Arad_Kulik_Shachnai_2022
Warning--empty journal in dosa_tight_2007
(There were 3 warnings)

Process exited normally



Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "SAGT2024".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "SAGT2024".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "SAGT2024".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "SAGT2024".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "SAGT2024".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "SAGT2024".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "SAGT2024".tex

Process exited normally

I counted 13 times that pdflatex.exe is run. Why does TexStudio run pdflatex so many times?

Off-topic: (a) The entry Doron-Arad_Kulik_Shachnai_2022 would appear to be of type @article but is missing two required fields: journal and volume. (b) The entry dosa_tight_2007 would also appear to be of type @article but is mssing one required field (journal). You may want to look into this matter; for instance, you may determine that the entries shouldn't have the @ariicle type to begin with.

On-topic: (a) What happens if you use a different front-end -- say, TeXworks -- to compile SAGT2024.tex?  (b) Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when was it last updated?
